# reducer returns null (react redux with router and params)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

i have a simple store where i have a getall and getbyid on a reducer

```
const initstate = {
   allobjects: [],
   object: {}
}

switch (action.type) {
    case Constant.GET_OBJECT:
      const object = state.allobjects.find(o => o.id === action.payload)
      return {
         ...state,
         object
      }
    case Constant.GET_ALL:
      const allobjects = action.payload
      return {
          ...state,
          allobjects
      }
}
```

i have two components:

```
// ObjectsList

export const ObjectList = ({ objects}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      // execute action to getobjects
    }, []) 
  return (
    <>
      {
        objects.map(o => > { <div>o.name</div>})
      }
    </>
  )
}

// mapstatetoprops return objects from init state
// mapdispatchtoprops that calls getobjects

export default connect(ObjectsList);


// Object

const Object = () => {
   const { obj_id } = userParams()
   useEffect(() => {
      // execute action to getobjbyid
    }, [])

   return (<div>selected {obj.name}</div>)
}

// mapstatetoprops return obj from init state
// mapdispatchtoprops that calls getobjectbyid

export connect(Object);
```

And then I use my react router dom to switch between these two components on the body.

```
const Container = () => {
  return (
     <>
         <Router exact path='/' component={ObjectsList} />
         <Router exact path='/:obj_id' component={Object} />
     </>
  )
}
```

I would then have the list of objects if I got to the path '/', but then if i got to the '/:obj_id' path, it would set my objects property (from init state) to null / []. only way it would not be null is if I visit the '/' route and have a link on the app to trigger the '/:obj_id' route.

My question is, what's the best way to deal with just going straight to the /obj_id route without having to load the objects list from the objectslist component?

Answer (score -1):

First of all subscribing to redux is wrongly done.
actual syntax: `connect()(Object)`

second reducer syntax is wrong, correct syntax:

```
YourReducer = (state = initialState, { type, data }) => {
      switch (action.type) {
         case Constant.GET_OBJECT:
           const object = state.allobjects.find(o => o.id === action.payload)
           return {
              ...state,
              object
           }
         case Constant.GET_ALL:
           const allobjects = action.payload
           return {
             ...state,
             allobjects
           }
         default: return state
     }
}
```

third:

use combineReducer which creates the redux state, correct syntax:

```
return combineReducer({
   myState: YourReducer
})
```

After all above are done then you can use the benefit of redux.